# Pycharm error "Process finished with exit code -1"

Tags: terminal, pycharm, exit

Before the program has been running normally, after the cloud desktop is updated, all programs will stop with "Process finished with exit code -1".

I used a very simple output program for testing. It simply outputs numbers from 0 to 100000000, and it will end with the above statement, and the stop position is different every time.

The test program I used is very simple, the program only has the following two lines.

for i in range(1000000000):
print(i)

I am using pycharm software programming.

The program was able to run normally before. Before and after the update of the cloud desktop, the program was not changed, the hardware and software of the server were not changed, and some hardware of the desktop was changed. The original desktop had a GPU, but the current desktop does not. But my program is only opened with pycharm on the desktop. The program is running on the server. In theory, it should still be able to run normally. Now, no matter what program is running, within one minute after running, it will end with "Process finished with exit code - 1" end.

If I output 0-10 or other relatively small numbers, the program will end normally, but when the number is relatively large, "Process finished with exit code -1" will appear. Some programs I want to run are also relatively For complicated ones, "exit code -1" will also appear

There is also no problem with the network connection between the desktop and the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, because there is a problem with the network connection between the desktop and the server, because the program is opened on the desktop and connected to the server through the network, and runs on the server. The network would disconnect intermittently, causing the program to abort.